# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have created a linkedIN, the only thing not working is when I try to post the content it says:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')

Firebase version is as follows

- firebase: ^9.1.2,
- firebase-tools: ^9.20.0,

I am facing issue at firebase "ref".

Below is the firebase configuration

firebase.js

```
//import { firebase } from "firebase";

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "**********************",
  authDomain: "*********************",
  projectId: "************************",
  storageBucket: "*********************",
  messagingSenderId: "*********************",
  appId: "***********************************",
};
    
//loading firebase configuration
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();`enter code here`
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = firebase.storage; //to store images

export { auth, provider, storage };

export default db;
```

This function has login where in when i click POST button, it post the content on LinkedIN app which i created(dummy)

index.js

```
import { auth, provider, storage } from "../firebase";

export function postArticleApi(payload) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    if (payload.image != "") {
      const upload = storage
        **.ref**(`images/${payload.image.name}`)
```

And when i click on POST button, it gives below error on browser :

```
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')
     export function postArticleApi(payload) {
      48 |   return (dispatch) => {
      49 |     if (payload.image != "") {
    > 50 |       const upload = storage
      51 |         .ref(`images/${payload.image.name}`)
      52 |         .put(payload.image);
      53 |       upload.on(
```

you can see at line 50 error is being pointing.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use `firebase.storage`, but you never import that in your `firebase.js`, which only contains:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

To fix the problem, also import storage in your `firebase.js` with:

```
import 'firebase/compat/storage';
```

And then initialize it (still in `firebase.js`) with:

```
const storage = firebase.storage();
```